# How to fix this infinite loop bug for Level Order Traversal Problem (Binary Trees)

Tags: c++, binary-tree, tree-traversal

Professor provided this code, but I keep getting an infinite loop. I also don't understand the auto keyword with ":" in for loops.

I can't seem to understand where the bug lies.

```
vector<int> levelOrder(TreeNode* root) {
    vector<int> res;
    if (root == NULL)
        return res;
    queue<TreeNode*> q;
    q.push(root);
    while (!q.empty()) {
        int size = q.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            TreeNode* curr = q.front();
            q.pop();
            if (curr->left != NULL) 
                q.push(curr->left);
            if (curr->right != NULL)
                q.push(curr->right);
            res.push_back(curr->data);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

...

int main () {
...
    vector<int> items = levelOrder(root);
    for (int item : items) {
        cout << item << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
...
        return 0;
}

Infinite Loop
```

Comment: `int size = q.size(); for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` -- If you look at the code carefully, you will realize that this serves no purpose.  The loop is controlled on the line(s) above this, i.e. (`while (!q.empty())`).  Unless the professor provided this code with the bug put in there on purpose, then I would be wary of the professor.

Comment: I realized the issue wasn't necessarily the code. It worked perfectly fine on VIM, but not on VSCode. The issue seems to be for range-based for loops. But you're right that the for loop is unnecessary. Any idea as to how to reformat the for loop?

Comment: The only ranged based `for` loop in your post is the one in `main`, and that one doesn't seem to be doing anything harmful.  The issue that I see is the level order traversal itself. -- *It worked perfectly fine on VIM, but not on VSCode.* -- Which means the program had one or more bugs.  Also VIM and VSCode are not compilers -- you probably were using g++ for one test and Visual Studio on the other.

Comment: Actually it seems like all range based for loops don't work on vscode for some reason. I tried a basic one on a new file, and none of them work without a return statement bug (I also did some examples where I copied and pasted, still doesn't work.)

Comment: Again, vscode is *not* a compiler.  You need to figure out the actual compiler you're using in vscode.  Maybe it is not C++ 11 compliant.

Answer (score 2):

First, the classical way to do a level-order traversal is to use a queue, and your code is doing that.

However, instead of relying on the state of the queue to loop using the `while(!q.empty())` condition, you have a totally unnecessary, and probably harmful inner `for` loop.  If you removed the inner loop, then the code should run correctly.

Example:

```
vector<int> levelOrder(TreeNode* root) {
    vector<int> res;
    if (!root)
        return res;
    queue<TreeNode*> q;
    q.push(root);
    while (!q.empty()) 
    {
        TreeNode* curr = q.front();
        q.pop();
        if (curr->left) 
            q.push(curr->left);
        if (curr->right)
            q.push(curr->right);
        res.push_back(curr->data);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I agree that the inner `for` loop is useless. (!) What I don't see is why it could cause harm. As far as I understood, it just provides an inner iteration over a whole level of tree while out loop is (needlessly) degraded to iterate over levels. Have I anything missed? (...beside of "Only dead code is good code.") ;-)